# Mixing ROS message versions

Tags: ros, catkin, message, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have a robot (Baxter) with an older version of a ROS message (say, control_msgs from Groovy), can I build the latest version (Indigo) in my local user's workspace on the robot and use that message instead?

By this I mean I source `/opt/ros/groovy/source.devel` and I have the old version of `control_msgs`

But then I build that message again in `~/catkin_ws/src/control_msgs` and source that workspace, I should no longer have issues with nodes built in my `catkin_ws` that need the newer version of the message, right?

In my testing, however, this does not work, so obviously roscore is tricker than this.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194967/mixing-ros-message-versions/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out my issue - it was really simple. I was building `control_msgs` from source but forgot to build `trajectory_msgs` from source, which is part of `common_msgs` which `control_msgs` depended on. Once I did that the md5 sum matched.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1